# Python consolidate dictionary keys and values using comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, consolidation

How do I CONSOLIDATE the following using python COMPREHENSION

**FROM (list of dicts)**

```
[
 {'server':'serv1','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder1'}
 ,{'server':'serv2','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder1'}
 ,{'server':'serv3','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder2'}
 ,{'server':'serv4','os':'AIX','archive':'/my/folder1'}
 ,{'server':'serv5','os':'AIX','archive':'/my/folder1'}
]
```

**TO (list of dicts with tuple as key and list of 'server#'s as value**

```
[
 {('Linux','/my/folder1'):['serv1','serv2']}
 ,('Linux','/my/folder2'):['serv3']}
 .{('AIX','/my/folder1'):['serv4','serv5']}
]
```

Comment: Comprehension isn't really the tool for this job...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the need to be able to set default values to your dictionary and to have the same key several times may make a dict-comprehension a bit clumsy. i'd prefer something like this:

a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) may help:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
 {'server':'serv1','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder1'},
 {'server':'serv2','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder1'},
 {'server':'serv3','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder2'},
 {'server':'serv4','os':'AIX','archive':'/my/folder1'},
 {'server':'serv5','os':'AIX','archive':'/my/folder1'}
]

dct = defaultdict(list)

for d in lst:
    key = d['os'], d['archive']
    dct[key].append(d['server'])
```

if you prefer to have a standard dictionary in the end (actually i do not really see a good reason for that) you could use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) in order to create an empty list where the key does not yet exist:

```
dct = {}

for d in lst:
    key = d['os'], d['archive']
    dct.setdefault(key, []).append(d['server'])
```

the [documentation on `defaultdict` (vs. `setdefault`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

> This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique
>   using dict.setdefault()

Comment: that's not using list comprehensions, but I don't think there's a way to do that with list comprehensions because of the cumulative effect.

Comment: Do you have any proof that it is faster?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre tried to find a version with comprehension first but the need to set a default value is tricky... will add a remark on that.

Comment: @shadow that is what the official python documentation says. did you benchmark?

Comment: Just a link to where the documentation states that will suffice.

Comment: I'm still newbie on python collections, so for now I'll use the standard dictionary @hiroprotagonist 2nd suggestion.  That's great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to achieve with list comprehension because of the accumulation effect. However, it's possible using `itertools.groupby` on the list sorted by your keys (use the same `key` function for both sorting and grouping).

Then extract the server info in a list comprehension and prefix by the group key. Pass the resulting (group key, server list) to dictionary comprehension and here you go.

```
import itertools

lst = [
 {'server':'serv1','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder1'}
 ,{'server':'serv2','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder1'}
 ,{'server':'serv3','os':'Linux','archive':'/my/folder2'}
 ,{'server':'serv4','os':'AIX','archive':'/my/folder1'}
 ,{'server':'serv5','os':'AIX','archive':'/my/folder1'}
]


sortfunc = lambda x : (x['os'],x['archive'])

result = {k:[x['server'] for x in v] for k,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(lst,key=sortfunc),key = sortfunc)}


print(result)
```

I get:

```
{('Linux', '/my/folder1'): ['serv1', 'serv2'], ('AIX', '/my/folder1'): ['serv4', 'serv5'], ('Linux', '/my/folder2'): ['serv3']}
```

Keep in mind that it's not because it can be written in one line that it's more efficient. The `defaultdict` approach doesn't require sorting for instance.